# Strange case with doctrine and/or symfony cache or something else

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, twig

Sf 2.6, Doctrine 2.
A little problem, db column has a default value (e.g. `private $visibleInCatalog = true;`), but when accessing this field in twig - default value is displayed instead of real. If I remove `= true` part then field value is `null` in twig. But(!), if I previously read this value in controller, like this:

```
    $prices = $entity->getPrices();
    $res = [];
    foreach ($prices as $price) {
        $res[] = $price->getVisibleInCatalog();
    }
```

Then in twig everything is ok - I got real values. By the way, this variable `$res` is not passed anywhere - it is just dumb read to get `visibleInCatalog` property of price entity and after that peace of code it is not used anywhere.
Product entity:

```
/**
 * 
 * @ORM\Table(name="product")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 *
 */
class Product extends AbstractEntityModel implements ContentInterface,     Sitemapable
{
    ...



    /**
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProductPrice", mappedBy="product", cascade={"all"}, orphanRemoval=true )
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"position" = "ASC"})
     */
    private $prices;
    ...
}
```

Price entity:

```
/**
 * 
 * @ORM\Table(name="product_price",
 *      uniqueConstraints={
 *          @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="ref_id_UNIQUE", columns={"ref_id"})
 *      },
 *      indexes={
 *          @ORM\Index(name="updat_idx", columns={"updated_at"})
 *      }
 * )
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class ProductPrice extends AbstractEntityModel implements ContentInterface
{
    ...
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="visible_in_catalog", type="boolean", options={"default"=true})
     */
    private $visibleInCatalog = true;
    ...
    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getVisibleInCatalog()
    {
        return $this->visibleInCatalog;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $visibleInCatalog
     */
    public function setVisibleInCatalog($visibleInCatalog)
    {
        $this->visibleInCatalog = $visibleInCatalog;
    }
}
```

Twig template:

```
{% for i,price in entity.prices.toArray %}
    {{ price.visibleInCatalog }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: try `{{ price.getVisibleInCatalog() }}` instead of `{{ price.visibleInCatalog }}`, is it any better ? if yes => twig issue, if not => doctrine issue

Comment: I tried it - no luck. Steps that I've tried: clear cache; clear doctrine metadata cache; read property in twig with getter instead of property name; dump data in property getter (in entity); and now only one provided me real data - dumb read in controller.

Comment: that is because `price` in your twig is actually a doctrine proxy object. It's supposed to be hydrated by doctrine (i.e. promoted to a full-blown entity with real database values) when you call one of its getter functions, for some reason it's not happening here. Maybe have a look at the generated proxy class source code and see if the getter code looks legit.

Comment: It's your prices.toArray which is defeating the lazy loading process.